# Can someone explain how the shortened code equals to the longer one?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me how

```
const { value, name } = event.target;
```

is equal to

```
event.target.name
event.target.value
```

Comment: It is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Also note the second thing you wrote is probably not what you meant, `const value = event.target.value; const name = event.target.name;` is the longhand version.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.
example for arrays :

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [y, z] = x;
console.log(y); // 1
console.log(z); // 2
```

another example for destructuring with objects

```
const user = {
id: 42,
is_verified: true
};

const {id, is_verified} = user;
console.log(id); // 42
console.log(is_verified); // true
```

reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment